# Sony NP-F battery terminal connector

Tags: batteries, connector

I'm looking to repair some electronic equipment and am scratching my head why the part I need is so hard to identify.

I recently had a bad connector on an Aputure Tri-8s LED light (Brand new out of the box) but had little intent to USE the battery terminals regularly and needed the light for a project. The connector was loose;  any shock to the battery would cause it to disconnect and infrequently minor arching could be heard. (I initially suspected a bad solder joint or something;  but this was not the case)

I don't personally like using warranty to "fix" such a trivial problem, the shipping cost alone would have been orders of magnitude more then the actual part or repair work, so I emailed the manufacturer and asked if they knew of a source of spare parts. (that was a few days ago;  I have not heard back yet)

In the meantime;  I (likely voided my warranty and) disassembled the product and found that the fault was simply a collapsed spring inside one of the battery terminals. (I actually managed to fix the existing connector by disassembling it, stretching the spring back out, and re-assembling the connector)

At first I assumed that the top pin would be retained using a rolled lip on the brass body; but these specific units are actually just press-fit and I was able to simply pull them apart and press them back together.

**POINT BEING;**
Sony NP-F style batteries;  appear to use a ~3mm (might be 2.97mm) spring-loaded pin contact.  I have not been able to locate a source for these contacts;  nor have I been able to find a model of the pins.

I assumed that given the common nature of these in the photo/video world;  many people would have experimented with building things that USED such batteries and I'd love to make a few adapter designs on a 3d printer:  but I am unable to determine the model / source of such pins.

Here's what they look like:

[image: NP-F Battery connector Male Pin]

I don't have *exact* dimensions but if anyone knows what terms I should be looking for,  I'd be happy to figure out the exact part from a supplier catalog.

The connectors are approximately 3mm in diameter;  and AROUND 12mm from the tip of the healthy pin to the end of the solder joint;  but I did not accurately measure these dimensions)

I'd love any literature on the NP-F battery integration;  if any such information exists.  I tried searching around online unsuccessfully.

---

I'm aware that this is not an EE question specifically;  but DIY electronics and product design didn't seem to have a better section.

Comment: I think there are a number of people who do experiment with this type of contact, however, you are unlikely to find the exact contact as often companies like sony have these made to their specifications. For experiments or prototyping, you would likely have to pick one of the hundreds of options available from someone like Digi-Key https://www.digikey.com/short/z3wf55

Comment: I made the assumption that I was not alone in wanting to source such connectors, but searching around online I'm not seeing any references at all. I guess I'll have to contact Harwin directly to see if they have such a connector and then see if I can find a source for a few dozen connectors (like digikey) thanks!!

Comment: You should be able to get these custom made from Mill-Max, but expect to pay a few thousand and get a thousand of them minimum.

Comment: "Pogo pIns" for test beds are not usually that short but may be suitable in a custom housing.

Comment: Many [here](https://www.cfeconn.com/spring-loaded/pogo-pin?gclid=CjwKCAjw6qqDBhB-EiwACBs6x6hWGHQGbfOtNJCbsqU7j7PXwQo7tgIhSjlBcE6p4Qm1Vgg1AhcDShoCrVsQAvD_BwE) - some very small

Answer (score 1):

I came upon this question while I was looking for a solution myself.

I did some further research and there's a [YouTube video by Thomas Sanladerer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pbm960k1wW4&t=361s) wherein he suggests to use 2.6mm mini-banana connectors that appear to be used in model trains.

[image: Image courtesy of Wikimedia]

I was able to source a couple of these and indeed, it seems to be a good fit and very usable.

Comment: Interesting, though I would consider the spring action crucial to these connectors given the various applications that these are used in.

Answer (score 1):

I have an unconventional and cheap suggestion which I'm going to try out for a similar issue. Lots of places sell battery chargers with interchangeable charging plates for a few dollars. I'm going to order a Sony NP-F plate, and take the pins out and put them on my light. Mind you, they're not the retractable spring-loaded ones, but they fit perfectly into the batteries, and from what I can tell, the battery release buttons don't actually affect the pins at all, on any of the devices I have that use NP-F style batteries.

[https://www.amazon.com/Watson-Battery-Charger-Adapter-Plate/dp/B00EHSLT38/ref=sr_1_4?crid=1L8U9YKE8H6WH&keywords=watson+NPF+charging+plate&qid=1647453285&sprefix=watson+npf+charging+plate%2Caps%2C66&sr=8-4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00EHSLT38)

[image: Watson Battery Adapter Plate for Sony L & M Series-Type Batteries on Amazon.com]

Image source: [Amazon - Watson Battery Adapter Plate for Sony L & M Series-Type Batteries](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00EHSLT38)

Answer (score 0):

The usual suspects have lots of options
Search Millmax, Harwin, and [Digikey](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/filter/contacts-spring-loaded-pogo-pins-and-pressure/311)

Comment: I've checked all three;  I cannot find anything even similar.  Milmax does not APPEAR to make anything over 0.092" (2.34mm) digikey has a single hit for a Preci-Dip part that would not fit (in this case)  and has a rather short travel distance of 1.65mm.

Comment: The Harwin however;  might work:  the P70-6000045R is _pretty close_   though the current rating is grossly low. (1A).  If Aputure spec'd the connectors for the Tri-8 properly;  they need to carry around 2A (each battery).   I wouldn't be all that surprised if in testing these contacts likely just loose lifespan in over-current applications.

Answer (score 0):

ATX 5.08 Connector pins are 2.6mm and has spring contacts, so should be a snug fit. I didn't test it myself yet, I'll update this answer after I test it.